# Command source disabling and enabling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I read all about WPF commanding and i understand the GoF Command Pattern, still thought, i have one question about the process: how does the command target (for example a text box) tell the command source ( a button for instance) that it has changed state (eg. some text inserted into the textbox) so that the source can disable or enable itself or what ever it wishes to do. to put it in another way, how does the command target let the ICommand implementing class (the cut command for example) to trigger it's CanExecuteChangedEvent so that class can in turn let the command source know about state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class called [CommandManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616838.aspx) taking care of execution logic. You can call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested method to let system check your CanExecute methods.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, so when a control such as a textbox changes state, the CommandManager knows about this and it uses command bindings on the target to tell the source of that state change. and if you know of any Article or blog detailing this process i would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know a decent article about this. I use either one of MVVM libs or create my own for each separate project. And those libs (mostly) register directly to the CommandManager and suggest triggering the event explicitly. Or I dont use CommandManager but trigger CanExecuteChanged internally.